# Linux: virtual interfaces with multicast

Tags: linux, networking, bridge, multicast, virtual-network

I have a Linux process which communicates with external world using TCP and UDP. Also it does send message over multicast. Now I want to test the communication by mocking external communication. I could create network namespaces and attach the process in test with one of the namespaces and attached the test application with other namespace. The communication works well. However network namespaces introduces complexities in my test scenario like debugging the process as I always attach namespace with it and needs to provide root access.

I wonder whether it can be done with setting 'tap' interfaces. I could setup 2 tap interfaces and achieve unicast communication. However I never got multicast worked.

Is there any way to enable multicast communication over tap interfaces?

Here is my tap network settings

```
sudo ip tuntap add dev tap0 mode tap    
sudo ip tuntap add dev tap1 mode tap    

sudo ip link set tap1 up            
sudo ip link set tap0 up

sudo ip addr add 192.168.7.2/24 dev tap0
sudo ip addr add 192.168.7.3/24 dev tap1
```

I even tried with adding bridge but still couldn't get multicast communication worked. I don't know much about networking. Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the other end of the tap interfaces connected to?

Comment: @user1686 I didn't connect the tap to anything. Just with the above setup I got the unicast working. BTW, I tried to added br0 bridge as master but there is no change in behavior.

Comment: If these tun/tap interfaces aren't used by an userspace network emulation tool (such as QEMU or OpenVPN) then they are useless. Mandatory link to understand it: https://backreference.org/2010/03/26/tuntap-interface-tutorial/index.html . Assigning the addresses on the main ethernet interface would have the same result (or assigning /32 addresses on the lo interface too). Using network namespaces is probably simpler because you get easily the network stack: the kernel provides it (multiple times).